# Automatically determine the natural language of a website page given its URL

Tags: python, url, web, nlp

I'm looking for a way to automatically determine the natural language used by a website page, given its URL.

In Python, a function like:

```
def LanguageUsed (url):
    #stuff
```

Which returns a language specifier (e.g. 'en' for English, 'jp' for Japanese, etc...)

Summary of Results:
I have a reasonable solution working in Python using [code from the PyPi for oice.langdet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oice.langdet/1.0dev-r781).
It does a decent job in discriminating English vs. Non-English, which is all I require at the moment.  Note that you have to fetch the html using Python urllib.  Also, oice.langdet is GPL license.

For a more general solution using Trigrams in Python as others have suggested, see this [Python Cookbook Recipe from ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/326576/).

The Google Natural Language Detection API works very well (if not the best I've seen).  However, it is Javascript and their TOS forbids automating its use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is usually accomplished by using character n-gram models. You can find [here](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/langid/read-me.html) a state of the art language identifier for Java. If you need some help converting it to Python, just ask. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet really is to use [Google's natural language detection](http://www.google.com/uds/samples/language/detect.html) api. It returns an iso code for the page language, with a probability index.

See http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing about the URL itself that will indicate language.

One option would be to use a [natural language toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) to try to identify the language based on the content, but even if you can get the NLP part of it working, it'll be pretty slow. Also, it may not be reliable. Remember, most user agents pass something like

```
Accept-Language: en-US
```

with each request, and many large websites will serve different content based on that header. Smaller sites will be more reliable because they won't pay attention to the language headers.

You could also use server location  (i.e. which country the server is in) as a proxy for language using [GeoIP](http://code.google.com/p/python-geoip/). It's obviously not perfect, but it is much better than using the TLD.

Comment: Geolocation is utterly useless. The world has plenty of places where multiple languages coexists. And websites may also feature multiple languages

Comment: All I said was that it's better than TLD, which some people are suggesting, and I addressed the multiple languages issue.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try ngram based detection.

[TextCat **DEMO**](http://www.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/Demo/textcat_src.html) (LGPL) seems to work pretty well (recognizes almost 70 languages). There is a python port provided by [Thomas Mangin](http://thomas.mangin.me.uk/) [here](http://thomas.mangin.me.uk/data/source/ngram.py) using the same corpus.

Edit: TextCat [competitors page](http://www.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/competitors.html) provides some interesting links too.

Edit2: I wonder if making a python wrapper for http://www.mnogosearch.org/guesser/ would be difficult...

Answer (score 1):

[nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) might help (if you have to get down to dealing with the page's text, i.e. if the headers and the url itself don't determine the language sufficiently well for your purposes); I don't think NLTK directly offers a "tell me which language this text is in" function (though NLTK is large and continuously growing, so it might in fact have it), but you can try parsing the given text according to various possible natural languages and checking which ones give the most sensible parse, wordset, &c, according to the rules for each language.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the langdetect package ([found here](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/)) can do this.
It is based on Googles automatic language detection and supports by default 55 languages.

It is installed by using

```
pip install langdetect
```

And then for example running

```
from langdetect import detect

detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")
```

Will return 'en' and 'de' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There's no general method that will work solely on URLs. You can check the [top-level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) to get some idea, and look for portions of the URL that might be indicative of a language (like "en" or "es" between two slashes), and assume anything unknown is in English, but it isn't a perfect solution.

So far as I know, the only general way to determine the natural language used by a page is to grab the page's text and check for certain common words in each language. For example, if "a", "an", and "the" appear several times in the page, it's likely that it includes English text; "el" and "la" might suggest Spanish; and so on.