# Recognizing language of a short text?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of articles, and each article has its own title and description. Unfortunately, from the sources I am using, there is no way to know what language they are written in.

Furthermore, the text is not entirely written in 1 language; almost always English words are present.

I reckon I would need dictionary databases stored on my machine, but it feels a bit impractical. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167262/automatically-determine-the-natural-language-of-a-website-page-given-its-url

Comment: Also the answer to this may make this question unnecessary, but not -- technically -- a duplicate.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88984/your-favorite-natural-language-parser

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd use the [guess-language](http://code.google.com/p/guess-language/) project.

Edit: Now in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language)

Comment: @Alex: thanks Alex. This is indeed very useful!

Comment: Note that the linked guess_language is now unmaintained and links to a [fork for both Python2 and Python3](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language).

Comment: langdetect is also an option

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into http://ling.unizd.hr/~dcavar/LID/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) if you don't mind using a web service to do your work for you.

Comment: Caveat: Google Translate API is a paid service.

Answer (score 2):

In general you're looking at doing nGram identification.  Since this is a python question, you might take a look at http://github.com/koblas/ngramj-python which is a pure python port of the java ngram library (another open source project).

The documentation is lacking, but it has really good accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but in case people come across this while researching options for this task, it is worth mentioning that another tool is [langid](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py).

Answer (score 1):

If neos recommendation is also unpractical, I would try something like this:

In many languages there are some keywords which are in many sentences and are often not found in other languages.

Example: "The" in English, "der", "die", "das" in German, ....

Find such words and try to find them in your texts. It can be a little fuzzy at last -- for example, when you find "the" and "der" -- it could be a German text containing some English sentences in it. At least with enough words from your target languages you could come to a high hit-rate.

Comment: That is what `guess-language` does.

Comment: @voyager: Thanks for the info. I guessed so ;-) No, I did not know the guess-language or other tools before. But I think, all these tools also can not do magic.

Comment: neither did I, but looked around a bit on the source and that is what it was doing. :)

Comment: Heads up : guess-language performs poorly... I tried it and it recognized some english text as non_english