# How to programmatically determine what language the content of a website is written in

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp

I would like to programmatically determine language that content of a website is written in.

The only thing that comes into my mind is to compare content of the website with some set of words that are common to the particular language, and based on match percentage determine the language.

Are there any better and more robust ways to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does language detection work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670427/how-does-language-detection-work)

Comment: Or [Automatically determine the natural language of a website page given its URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167262/automatically-determine-the-natural-language-of-a-website-page-given-its-url), or a slew of other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural Network tutorial with Language classifying example 
based on average frequencies of the letters
http://fann.sourceforge.net/fann_en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you can use an API (instead of having to write your own), have a look at this particular answer to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api/8121813#8121813

Quote:

> If you just need language detection, you can use free web service:
>
> http://detectlanguage.com
>
> It is compatible with Google Translate API request/response formats.

Comment: The resources there, however, are useful if the goal is to translate the text in addition to finding its language; the asker, however, seems to be interested only in finding the natural language of some text.

Comment: The specific answer I linked to provides language detection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have a preference for specific languages, but Python also has a package for language detection, called **[langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/)**.

Compared to the other proposed methods, it has the advantage of being:

- **Offline**, so no extra API calls required.
- Ready out of the box. No custom training is needed.

It is based on Googles automatic language detection and supports by default 55 languages.

### Installation

You can install it by using

```
pip install langdetect
```

And then for example running

```
from langdetect import detect

detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")
```

Will return 'en' and 'de' respectively.

This assumes that you already have the content of the site available as clean text. If you need to download the content, you can for example use the [requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).